# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a Httprequest to web api and  i am including the username and password in request header, but i get `The format of value 'dGVzdGNsaWVudDAyOnBhc3MwMg==' is invalid`

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        String userName = "testclient02";
        String userPassword = "pass02";

        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

       // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", authInfo);//if use this i get 2 authorization tags in header- Authorization: Authorization XXXXXXXXX===
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authInfo.ToString());//error here

        var result = client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:007/api/XXX")).Result;
```

edit: This my decoding code

```
  public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public User ObjUser;
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokens = request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault();
                if (tokens != null)
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(tokens);
                    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                    string[] tokensValues = decodedString.Split(':');

                    ObjUser = new CredentialChecker().CheckCredential(tokensValues[0], tokensValues[1]);
               }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using basic authentication then create `AuthenticationHeaderValue` like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);
```

See [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) as a reference.

Comment: Can you please give me some suggestions/code sample to decode with basic authentication

Comment: @prasy take a look at this blog: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter